# tensorflow protobuf conflict when compiling with third party framework

Tags: c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, conflict

I built my own tensorflow c++ library(with protobuf 3.4).

When compiling with the network framework, there is a big problem. The network framework depends on protobuf 2.5. And I can't change the protobuf of the network framework, no one is maintenance this project.

Can I build tensorflow library with a stand-alone namespace? And how to configure this?

Comment: Can you show what errors you get when you try to do the above?

Comment: hers is the error msg:    what():  This program requires version 3.4.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.5.0.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/any.pb.cc".)

Answer (score 0):

I also get this issue in using opencv and tensorflow together on iOS. Anyone with a solution?

Comment: overwrite the tensorflow/tf_exported_symbols.lds file, and delete the items you don't want to export.